# Put part of Filename in line 8

Tags: powershell, line, filenames

I habe some files, they are all named after the same scheme (Wien - Number - Text, e.g. Wien - 001 - Text, Wien - 002 - Text). The files are nfo.
They have nfo files, but they are not correct, I was able to delete the wrong entry with advanced renamer.
Now I want to put the Number in line 8 of the nfo file.
I got this to work with only one file but I have several files in one folder and I haven't got this to work.

Here is my script

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.nfo" | Foreach-Object{

$baseName = $_.BaseName

$array = $baseName -Split ' - '

$addToFile = '<episode>' + $array[1] + '</episode>'

$filePath = ".\*.nfo"
$fileContent = Get-Content $filePath
$lineNumber = "8"
$textToAdd = $addToFile
$fileContent[$lineNumber-1] = $textToAdd 
$fileContent | Set-Content $filePath

}
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a good problem description. You should describe what the code is actually doing and why that's wrong. That said, my guess would be to replace `$filePath = ".\*.nfo"` with `$filePath = $_.FullName` and `$lineNumber = "8"` with `$lineNumber = 8`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was the problem, the filepath was wrong. It worked with $_.FullName

Answer (score 0):

As [Bacon Bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72979465/put-part-of-filename-in-line-8#comment128898557_72979465) already commented, you're not using the ful path and filename of the file where you already have that in `$_.FullName`.

Also, you could do with a lot less 'in-between' variables.

Try

```
$lineNumber = 8
Get-ChildItem -Path 'X:\WhereTheFilesAre' -Filter "* - *.nfo" | Foreach-Object {
    $fileContent = Get-Content -Path $_.FullName
    $fileContent[$lineNumber-1] = '<episode>{0}</episode>' -f ($_.BaseName -split ' - ')[1]
    $fileContent | Set-Content $_.FullName
}
```

<sup>`'<episode>{0}</episode>' -f ($_.BaseName -split ' - ')[1]` is a very nice way to create a new string using the [Format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-7.1#format-operator--f)</sup>